# PCF Component save data to SingleLineText

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-dynamics, pcf

i have a small problem:

I coded a checklist for MS Dynamics 365 as a pcf component.
Now I have the problem that i can't save the data.

The Checklist's data is stored in a JSON format.

I want to store this JSON in the entity.

This is my property.
`<property name="saveCheckList" display-name-key="datom_saveCheckList" description-key="Property_Desc_Key" of-type="SingleLine.TextArea" usage="bound" required="true" />`

Can you please tell me how I store the data. Thank you!
If you need more informations do't worry to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to ensure that the PCF method getOutputs returns the data being stored in your component code. For example, we store a JSON in the control and if we want the control to tell the Dynamics 365 to save the actual data, we use it like this:

```
/**
     * It is called by the framework prior to a control receiving new data.
     * @returns an object based on nomenclature defined in manifest, expecting object[s] for property marked as “bound” or “output”
     */
    public getOutputs(): IOutputs {  
        // Our method to retrieve JSON.
        let data = this.priceIndexationData.getData();

        // And we tell the framework to save the JSON to bound property (declared in control's manifest)
        return { priceIndexationData: data }
    }
```

Manifest line of declaring the "priceIndexationData" in our case:

```
<property name="priceIndexationData" display-name-key="Price Indexation Data" description-key="ken_priceindexationdata field value." of-type="Multiple" usage="bound" required="true" />
```

Comment: And how can I access the data which is already stored in the ms dynamics 365 field. So I can fill my control with the existing data?

Comment: Well the bound type property always exist in Context<IInputs> object, so for example in the init() method of the framework, you can get the value that is stored in Dynamics by accesing the context.parameters property. In our example, we would get the value from dynamics by accessing context.parameters.priceIndexationData.raw